# Python scraping an expandable table(BeautifulSoup)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a conflicting issue that i cant seem to find online.

I want to scrape a table from this website: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html
and this is the table i wanted to scrape:
[image]

So i was able to scrape it, but! it stops until the show all part button.
Is there a way for me to be able to expand this table and then scrape it?

Here is my code(Its a mess as I just wrote it, but enought to get the idea)

```
def connect_add():
    #giving URL a var
    url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/world/covid-vaccinations-tracker.html'

    #Sending request to URL
    req = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
    tble = soup.find("table", class_="svelte-2wimac")
    
    table_rows = tble.find_all('tr')
    
    data = []
    
    for rows in table_rows:
        prepare = []
        for td in rows.find_all('td'):
            x  = td.text
            prepare.append(x)
        data.append(prepare)

    df_side = pd.DataFrame(data)
    x = df_side.head(50)
    display(x)

    
connect_add()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source. You can use this example how to load it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(
    "https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/19/world-vaccinations-tracker/3bf66651fd690992142ef2a7e233e8fdedcdd6c5/latest.json"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        geoid                          location last_updated  total_vaccinations  population  people_vaccinated  people_fully_vaccinated
0         DZA                           Algeria   2021-02-19               75000    43053054                NaN                      NaN
1         MOZ                        Mozambique   2021-03-23               57305    30366036            57305.0                      NaN
2         CPV                        Cape Verde   2021-03-24                2184      549935             2184.0                      NaN
3         MUS                         Mauritius   2021-03-24              117323     1265711           117323.0                      NaN
4         STP             Sao Tome and Principe   2021-03-29                9724      215056             9724.0                      NaN
5         ARM                           Armenia   2021-03-31                 565     2957731              565.0                      NaN
6         MMR                           Myanmar   2021-03-31             1040000    54045420          1000000.0                  40000.0
7         SYR                             Syria   2021-04-08                2500    17070135             2500.0                      NaN
8         HND                          Honduras   2021-04-09               57639     9746117            55000.0                   2639.0
9         TCA          Turks and Caicos Islands   2021-04-11               25039       38191            15039.0                  10000.0
10        VEN                         Venezuela   2021-04-12              250000    28515829           250000.0                      NaN
11        JAM                           Jamaica   2021-04-13              135473     2948279           135473.0                      NaN
12        COG                             Congo   2021-04-14               14297     5380508            14297.0                      NaN
13        FLK                  Falkland Islands   2021-04-14                4407        3398             2632.0                   1775.0
14        TLS                             Timor   2021-04-14                2629     1293119             2629.0                      NaN
15        NRU                             Nauru   2021-04-15                 700       12581              700.0                      NaN
16        SSD                       South Sudan   2021-04-15                 947    11062113              947.0                      NaN
17        FJI                              Fiji   2021-04-16               56000      889953            56000.0                      NaN
18        DJI                          Djibouti   2021-04-17               10246      973560            10246.0                      NaN
19        LSO                           Lesotho   2021-04-17               16000     2125268            16000.0                      NaN
20        LBY                             Libya   2021-04-17                 750     6777452              750.0                      NaN
21        NER                             Niger   2021-04-17                1366    23310715             1366.0                      NaN
22        SOM                           Somalia   2021-04-17              117567    15442905           117567.0                      NaN
23        TGO                              Togo   2021-04-17              160000     8082366           160000.0                      NaN
24        EGY                             Egypt   2021-04-18              660000   100388073           660000.0                      NaN
25        MRT                        Mauritania   2021-04-18                7038     4525696             7038.0                      NaN
26        SGP                         Singapore   2021-04-18             2213888     5703569          1364124.0                 849764.0
27        COM                           Comoros   2021-04-21               13440      850886            13440.0                      NaN
28        MSR                        Montserrat   2021-04-21                1909        5900             1293.0                    616.0
29        AFG                       Afghanistan   2021-04-22              240000    38041754           240000.0                      NaN
30        AIA                          Anguilla   2021-04-22                6898       14731             6115.0                    783.0
31        ATG               Antigua and Barbuda   2021-04-22               29754       97118            29754.0                      NaN
32        MCO                            Monaco   2021-04-22               24390       38964            12758.0                  11632.0
33        AGO                            Angola   2021-04-23              456349    31825295           456349.0                      NaN
34        BLR                           Belarus   2021-04-23              328500     9466856           244000.0                  84500.0
35        BRN                            Brunei   2021-04-23               10715      433285            10715.0                      NaN
36        GAB                             Gabon   2021-04-23                8897     2172579             6895.0                   2002.0
37        IRQ                              Iraq   2021-04-23              298377    39309783           298377.0                      NaN
38        SDN                             Sudan   2021-04-23              140227    42813238           140227.0                      NaN
39        GMB                            Gambia   2021-04-24               20922     2347706            20922.0                      NaN
40        NIC                         Nicaragua   2021-04-24              135130     6545502           135130.0                      NaN
41        COD      Democratic Republic of Congo   2021-04-25                1700    86790567             1700.0                      NaN
42        SWZ                          Eswatini   2021-04-25               34897     1148130            34897.0                      NaN
43        MLI                              Mali   2021-04-25               49903    19658031            49903.0                      NaN
44        PSE                         Palestine   2021-04-25              213989     4685306           170109.0                  43880.0
45        PNG                  Papua New Guinea   2021-04-25                2900     8776109             2900.0                      NaN
46        GUY                            Guyana   2021-04-26              126800      782766           124000.0                   2800.0
47        LAO                              Laos   2021-04-26              184387     7169455           126072.0                  58315.0
48        TON                             Tonga   2021-04-26                5367      104494             5367.0                      NaN
49        BHS                           Bahamas   2021-04-27               25692      389482            25692.0                      NaN
50        BIH            Bosnia and Herzegovina   2021-04-27              106464     3301000            83260.0                  23204.0
51        SLB                   Solomon Islands   2021-04-27                4890      669823             4890.0                      NaN
52        UZB                        Uzbekistan   2021-04-27              600369    33580650           600369.0                      NaN
53        GNQ                 Equatorial Guinea   2021-04-28               75518     1355986            64646.0                  10872.0
54        KEN                             Kenya   2021-04-28              853081    52573973           853081.0                      NaN
55        KGZ                        Kyrgyzstan   2021-04-28               27858     6456900            27000.0                    858.0
56        CMR                          Cameroon   2021-04-29               11000    25876380            11000.0                      NaN
57        BWA                          Botswana   2021-04-30               49882     2303697            49882.0                      NaN
58        GHA                             Ghana   2021-04-30              849527    30417856           849527.0                      NaN
59        VNM                           Vietnam   2021-04-30              509855    96462106           509855.0                      NaN
60        VCT  Saint Vincent and the Grenadines   2021-05-01               14526      110589                NaN                      NaN
61        BMU                           Bermuda   2021-05-02               58193       63918            32877.0                  25216.0
62        NLD                       Netherlands   2021-05-02             5651843    17332850          4448730.0                      NaN
63        PRY                          Paraguay   2021-05-02              143441     7044636           131013.0                  12428.0
64        AND                           Andorra   2021-05-03               28881       77142            24182.0                   4699.0
65        BOL                           Bolivia   2021-05-03              878563    11513100           637694.0                 240869.0
66        CRI                        Costa Rica   2021-05-03              950252     5047561           605099.0                 345153.0
67        WSM                             Samoa   2021-05-03                7435      197097                NaN                      NaN
68        SYC                        Seychelles   2021-05-03              127721       97625            68045.0                  59676.0
69        JOR                            Jordan   2021-05-04             1091048    10101694           805020.0                 286028.0
70        NZL                       New Zealand   2021-05-04              304900     4917000           217603.0                  87297.0
71        KNA             Saint Kitts and Nevis   2021-05-04               13070       52834            12943.0                    127.0
72        ETH                          Ethiopia   2021-05-05             1215934   112078730                NaN                      NaN
73        LIE                     Liechtenstein   2021-05-05               13829       38019             9645.0                   4184.0
74        MLT                             Malta   2021-05-05              359429      502653           246698.0                 112731.0
75        OMN                              Oman   2021-05-05              326269     4974986           253000.0                  73269.0
76        CHE                       Switzerland   2021-05-05             3001029     8574832          1997717.0                1003312.0
77        CYP                            Cyprus   2021-05-06              332423     1198575           252792.0                  79631.0
78        SLV                       El Salvador   2021-05-06             1114544     6453553           958828.0                 155716.0
79        GRD                           Grenada   2021-05-06               17000      112003            13000.0                   4000.0
80        KWT                            Kuwait   2021-05-06             1440000     4207083                NaN                      NaN
81        LBN                           Lebanon   2021-05-06              509705     6855713           325383.0                 184322.0
82        LUX                        Luxembourg   2021-05-06              227314      619896           165376.0                  61938.0
83        NOR                            Norway   2021-05-06             1919369     5347896          1465851.0                 453518.0
84        PAK                          Pakistan   2021-05-06             3320304   216565318                NaN                      NaN
85        PER                              Peru   2021-05-06             1939155    32510453          1284692.0                 654463.0
86        ESP                             Spain   2021-05-06            19048132    47076781         13271511.0                5956451.0
87        BLZ                            Belize   2021-05-07               47675      390353            47675.0                      NaN
88        BRA                            Brazil   2021-05-07            46875460   211049527         31722544.0               15152916.0
89        CYM                    Cayman Islands   2021-05-07               69772       64948            37470.0                  32302.0
90        COL                          Colombia   2021-05-07             6096661    50339443          3861416.0                2235245.0
91        DMA                          Dominica   2021-05-07               32008       71808            18864.0                  13144.0
92        ECU                           Ecuador   2021-05-07             1245822    17373662           981620.0                 264202.0
93        DEU                           Germany   2021-05-07            34408840    83132799         26872478.0                7572228.0
94        GRL                         Greenland   2021-05-07               14278       56225             8994.0                   5284.0
95        GIN                            Guinea   2021-05-07              173623    12771246           116436.0                  57187.0
96        ISL                           Iceland   2021-05-07              184304      361313           138577.0                  53658.0
97        IRN                              Iran   2021-05-07             1485287    82913906          1231652.0                 253635.0
98        IRL                           Ireland   2021-05-07             1799190     4941444          1305178.0                 494012.0
99        KAZ                        Kazakhstan   2021-05-07             2158924    18513930          1634939.0                 523985.0
100       NAM                           Namibia   2021-05-07               36417     2494530            34346.0                   2071.0
101       NPL                             Nepal   2021-05-07             2453512    28608710          2091511.0                 362001.0
102       RWA                            Rwanda   2021-05-07              350400    12626950           350400.0                      NaN
103       SMR                        San Marino   2021-05-07               34011       33860            21389.0                  12622.0
104       SWE                            Sweden   2021-05-07             3679451    10285453          2852689.0                 826762.0
105       UGA                            Uganda   2021-05-07              395805    44269594           395805.0                      NaN
106       ALB                           Albania   2021-05-08              596766     2854191                NaN                      NaN
107       ABW                             Aruba   2021-05-08               80699      106314            55744.0                  24955.0
108       BRB                          Barbados   2021-05-08               75476      287025            75476.0                      NaN
109       BEL                           Belgium   2021-05-08             4591359    11484055          3527895.0                1084263.0
110       BTN                            Bhutan   2021-05-08              481491      763092           481491.0                      NaN
111       CHL                             Chile   2021-05-08            15703842    18952038          8559854.0                7143988.0
112       DNK                           Denmark   2021-05-08             2339464     5818553          1489198.0                 850266.0
113       DOM                Dominican Republic   2021-05-08             2345528    10738958          1535083.0                 810445.0
114       FIN                           Finland   2021-05-08             2154469     5520314          1943842.0                 210627.0
115       FRA                            France   2021-05-08            25414386    67059887         17692900.0                7832913.0
116       GEO                           Georgia   2021-05-08               58533     3720382            58533.0                      NaN
117       GIB                         Gibraltar   2021-05-08               74256       33701            38727.0                  35529.0
118       GRC                            Greece   2021-05-08             3647689    10716322          2450349.0                1197340.0
119       GTM                         Guatemala   2021-05-08              206951    16604026           204459.0                   2492.0
120       MDV                          Maldives   2021-05-08              431792      530953           300906.0                 130886.0
121       MEX                            Mexico   2021-05-08            21228359   127575529         14148207.0                9440251.0
122       MDA                           Moldova   2021-05-08              184660     2657637           161266.0                  23394.0
123       MAR                           Morocco   2021-05-08             9864561    36471769          5473809.0                4390752.0
124       POL                            Poland   2021-05-08            13670541    37970874         10185393.0                3650119.0
125       ROU                           Romania   2021-05-08             5891855    19356544          3580368.0                2314812.0
126       LCA                       Saint Lucia   2021-05-08               25200      182790                NaN                      NaN
127       SEN                           Senegal   2021-05-08              427377    16296364           427377.0                      NaN
128       SLE                      Sierra Leone   2021-05-08               64966     7813215            58250.0                   6716.0
129       SVK                          Slovakia   2021-05-08             1792674     5454073          1209044.0                 583630.0
130       ZAF                      South Africa   2021-05-08              382480    58558270           382480.0                 382480.0
131       SUR                          Suriname   2021-05-08               90338      581363            45420.0                  44918.0
132       TUN                           Tunisia   2021-05-08              499369    11694719           350426.0                 148943.0
133       UKR                           Ukraine   2021-05-08              863085    44385155           862639.0                    446.0
134       GBR                    United Kingdom   2021-05-08            53041048    66834405         35371669.0               17669379.0
135       ZMB                            Zambia   2021-05-08               77348    17861030            77348.0                      NaN
136       ARG                         Argentina   2021-05-09             9082597    44938712          7688877.0                1393720.0
137       AUS                         Australia   2021-05-09             2654338    25364307                NaN                      NaN
138       AUT                           Austria   2021-05-09             3632879     8877067          2665516.0                 972493.0
139       AZE                        Azerbaijan   2021-05-09             1687397    10023318          1005678.0                 681719.0
140       BHR                           Bahrain   2021-05-09             1375967     1641172           797181.0                 578786.0
141       BGD                        Bangladesh   2021-05-09             9316086   163046161          5819900.0                3496186.0
142       BGR                          Bulgaria   2021-05-09              938064     6975761           646068.0                 291996.0
143       KHM                          Cambodia   2021-05-09             2884922    16486542          1773994.0                1110928.0
144       CAN                            Canada   2021-05-09            15917555    37589262         14668624.0                1248931.0
145       CHN                             China   2021-05-09           324307000  1397715000                NaN                      NaN
146       CIV                     Cote d'Ivoire   2021-05-09              262639    25716544           262639.0                      NaN
147       HRV                           Croatia   2021-05-09             1131607     4067500           879312.0                 252295.0
148       CUW                           Curacao   2021-05-09              109444      157538            77141.0                  32303.0
149       CZE                           Czechia   2021-05-09             3654376    10669709          2610990.0                1058179.0
150       EST                           Estonia   2021-05-09              532605     1326590           373391.0                 159214.0
151       FRO                    Faeroe Islands   2021-05-09               23519       48678            16896.0                   6623.0
152       HKG                         Hong Kong   2021-05-09             1741682     7451000          1071488.0                 670194.0
153       HUN                           Hungary   2021-05-09             6809350     9769949          4305775.0                2503575.0
154       IND                             India   2021-05-09           168304868  1366417754        133854676.0               34450192.0
155       IDN                         Indonesia   2021-05-09            21993299   270625568         13349469.0                8643830.0
156       IMN                       Isle of Man   2021-05-09               75783       84584            59932.0                  15851.0
157       ISR                            Israel   2021-05-09            10501225     9053300          5422082.0                5079143.0
158       ITA                             Italy   2021-05-09            24054000    60297396         16823066.0                7401862.0
159       JPN                             Japan   2021-05-09             4436325   126264931          3277886.0                1158439.0
160       LVA                            Latvia   2021-05-09              395512     1912789           316665.0                  79647.0
161       LTU                         Lithuania   2021-05-09             1162170     2786844           777019.0                 385151.0
162       MAC                             Macao   2021-05-09              118687      631636            77597.0                  41241.0
163       MWI                            Malawi   2021-05-09              319323    18628747           319323.0                      NaN
164       MYS                          Malaysia   2021-05-09             1766651    31949777          1089637.0                 677014.0
165       MNG                          Mongolia   2021-05-09             2213376     3225167          1590636.0                 622740.0
166       MNE                        Montenegro   2021-05-09              109507      622137            78760.0                  30747.0
167       NGA                           Nigeria   2021-05-09             1665698   200963599          1665698.0                      NaN
168       MKD                   North Macedonia   2021-05-09              107978     2083459           107978.0                      NaN
169       PAN                            Panama   2021-05-09              780569     4246439           524958.0                 255610.0
170       PHL                       Philippines   2021-05-09             2408781   108116615          1957511.0                 451270.0
171       PRT                          Portugal   2021-05-09             3963372    10269417          2858389.0                1104961.0
172       QAT                             Qatar   2021-05-09             1813240     2832067          1115842.0                 697398.0
173       RUS                            Russia   2021-05-09            21754829   144373535         13129704.0                8625125.0
174       SAU                      Saudi Arabia   2021-05-09            10584301    34268528                NaN                      NaN
175       SRB                            Serbia   2021-05-09             3798942     6944975          2149705.0                1649237.0
176       SVN                          Slovenia   2021-05-09              737817     2087946           484949.0                 252868.0
177       KOR                       South Korea   2021-05-09             4181003    51709098          3674729.0                 506274.0
178       LKA                         Sri Lanka   2021-05-09             1125740    21803000           928400.0                 197340.0
179       TWN                            Taiwan   2021-05-09               92049    23780452                NaN                      NaN
180       THA                          Thailand   2021-05-09             1809894    69625582          1296440.0                 513454.0
181       TTO               Trinidad and Tobago   2021-05-09               61120     1394973            60174.0                    946.0
182       TUR                            Turkey   2021-05-09            24918773    83429615         14585980.0               10332793.0
183       ARE              United Arab Emirates   2021-05-09            11145934     9770529                NaN                      NaN
184       URY                           Uruguay   2021-05-09             2005442     3461734          1228151.0                 777291.0
185       ZWE                          Zimbabwe   2021-05-09              684243    14645468           526066.0                 158177.0
186       USA                     United States   2021-05-09           259716989   331811257        152116936.0              114258244.0
187  OWID_WRL                             World          NaN          1297259952  7673533970        641081197.0              309613453.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue how you created that json link, but I wanted to know if there was anything I could do with my code/BeautifulSoup? because that is taking all the tables.

Comment: @King When you open Firefox Developer Tools->Network tab, you'll see there all requests the page is doing. One of the request is this url with json data. The javascript on the page then renders this data.